Why is 前のめり here being used with the で?
日向さんが前のめりで僕を組合へと誘う理由を知りたいと」
The character summarizes what his friend says: "So you want to know why Hinata-san was to invite me to the group"
As far I can see 前のめりで here is being used like ad adverb, so why the で used?

Can you elaborate? Most particles (で, へ, に, から, と, まで) take a noun and form adverbial (verb-modifying) phrases. Creating an adverbial phrase is the fundamental function of で, isn't it?

This で is a condition/scope/method particle that takes various nouns and forms an adverbial expression.

How should I understand 追加で in this sentence?
help with breaking down this sentence: 私が今まで見た中で最も面白いもの

Similarly, 前のめり is a noun, and 前のめりで means "learning forward" (physically) or "eagerly" (figuratively). It adverbially modifies 誘う.

日向さんが前のめりで僕を組合へと誘う理由を知りたいと。
(So you're saying) you want to know why Hinata-san is so eagerly inviting me to the group.



日向さんが[前]{●}[の]{●}[め]{●}[り]{●}で僕を組合へと誘う理由を知りたいと

As we can see in the monolingual 日本国語大辞典【にほんほくごだいじてん】 entry here at Kotobank (second entry section down), this word 前のめり【まえのめり】 is classed as a combination noun / -na adjective.
As such, from basic syntax and grammar, this use of で in the context of the sample sentence can be understood in English as roughly "is, and", basically the conjunctive form of the copula だ and serving the same "[VERB], and" conjunctive role as the -te form of verbs:

日向さんが[前]{●}[の]{●}[め]{●}[り]{●}で僕を組合へと誘う理由を知りたいと
↓
Hyūga / Hinata / etc.-san is proactive, and wants to know the reasons for inviting me into the association


This で is a particle, not a copula.

@naruto, I think it depends on the analysis, no? Some writers talk about で and な as different forms of the copula だ, for instance.

Sometimes it depends on the analysis, but in this case, it's a particle. OP is saying the subject of 知りたい is "you", and 前のめり describes the manner of 誘う.
